# Images chopped horizontally on ADE

Tags: epub, image, metadata, opf

I have about 20 images in an epub (on various xhtml pages).
My prepped epub shows its images (when tested on cell phone):

- OK on Kobo App [with .kepub.epub extension set]
- OK on PocketBook eReader
- OK on Aldiko eReader
- OK on Moon+ eReader
- some are chopped on ADE (Adobe Digital Editions)

On ADE various images get chopped or sliced off horizontally as if the images are not fully loading (being hindered at load time), and yet some of the other images fully load just fine. The chopped images vary where it gets sliced off during the partial load. All the JPG images width are of similar setup -- about 1000px wide, at 120 resolution, about 300kb average.

I doubt that it's the CSS coding, since the images render perfect in all those other eReaders.

Is must be caused from a factor in either the page `<head>` such as incorrect parameters (I've tested it by changing that info based on reading IDPF docs and epub3 docs but no solution yet). Or perhaps its an incorrect setting in the '`package`' or '`metadata`' part of the OPF file?

And, when I clear the cell phone cache, reload the epub, the images that get sliced off might now be fully visible, while a previously fully visible image now gets sliced up partway down.
And, when I prepare to finger slide to the next page with a flick of the finger, the non-visible image becomes partly visible, then freezes during partial load, and the page turns to the next page.
I've not encountered this on other smaller epubs we've created that have few images, but this one latest project is loaded with imagery (the zipped epub is 25mb total).

This issue doesn't occur where a photo is the full page (and has no text) -- where we have a folder that has 30 images for 30 full pages.

Has anyone encountered this odd problem before and found a solution?
Epubcheck validates and indicates nothing.

Or...is this an ADE eReader software glitch?

[image: Image chopped example]